# C++ | Class working on arbitrary struct member

Tags: c++, class, templates, structure

I want to have a class that has a member of an arbitrary struct type. The class should have a method that can alter the value of an arbitrary field of the struct member and another method that does something with the entire struct member (like outputting all its fields).

I achieved this in the following way:

```cpp
struct myStruct1
{
    int age;
    double height;
};


struct myStruct2
{
    float weight;
};

template<typename T, typename S>
class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass(T& structure, S& field)
            : _structure {structure}
            , _field {field}
        {}

        void alterField(double newVal)
        {
            _field = static_cast<S>(newVal);
        }

        void outputFields()
        {
            // code that outputs fields
            // uses _structure
            // otherwise not important
        }

    private:
        T& _structure;
        S& _field;
};

int main() {
    myStruct1 structInstance1 {14, 1.63};
    myClass<myStruct1, int> classInstance1 {structInstance1 , structInstance1.age};

    myStruct2 structInstance2 {75.6};
    myClass<myStruct2, float> classInstance2 {structInstance2, structInstance2.weight};

    classInstance1.alterField(15);
    classInstance1.outputFields();

    classInstance2.alterField(73.8);
    classInstance2.outputFields();
}
```

However, I have to instantiate the structures every time this way (see line `myStruct1 structInstance1 {14, 1.63};`). Instead, I would like the structures' instances only to exist within the class objects. I do not know how to achieve this and still be able to alter an arbitrary field of the structure. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The above code won't compile. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding `;`.

Comment: Unrelated: Having reference members is usually a bad idea.

Comment: This has been tried so often (usually by programmers coming from other languages to C++), and it is just not how C++ works. Just create getter and setter functions (that can also check your input).

Comment: Also what @user12002570 says. Reference members can be used but if and only if you are 100% sure by design that the object using those reference has a shorter lifetime then the objects they refer to.

Comment: @PepijnKramer That's equally true for pointers which are ubiquitous in legacy code -- it's the general problem of ownership. Why the focus on references? Because it's not as obvious to the caller that the "per value" pass is actually a "per reference" pass?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You're absolutely right, it is a more generic problem. I just didn't think about generalizing my answer ;)

Comment: what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need "a class that has a member of an arbitrary struct type" ? Suppose it would work as you wish, then what would you do with that? If you explain the usecase perhaps we can tell you a simpler way to achieve it

Comment: @PepijnKramer My issue with references vs. pointers is that it seems inevitable that at some point in the code's lifetime a legitimate case will come up where the object should be created before the reference is available (even if it's just a test), and then people start using referencing null pointers and such. It's simply too constrained at design time, similar to a well-meant input field validation that checks for American phone number formats (and then makes it impossible to serve international customers).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I can see that point. I use references in my designs but mostly in dependency injection scneraios with well known lifecycles. So in the case of a test I can always inject a stub...  But yes if lifeccyle is not guaranteed (raw non-owning) pointers will do.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Just look inside the STL and you will see plenty of pointers. If you don't use pointers you are leaving 90% of the power of C++ on the table. Then perhaps it's better to use C#, Java or Rust.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Haha no, no C# or java for me. Too much reference semantics there. I am not making my point very clear I think. There is room for (raw) pointers, smart pointers, references, std::optional and and depending on the use case I use them all. I think we're stealing a bit too much of OP's question now ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer  I think Rust is a better choice than C++ if you elect to use value semantics 100% as a matter of style. Rust replaces Modern C++. The borrow checker is way more advanced than `std::move`, for example. You should consider it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai You asked me to clarify my intentions. I am writing a module for the PX4 autopilot firmware for drone flight controllers (https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot). Among other things, the module reads values from some source and publishes the values in uORB topics. In order to "publish a uORB topic", one has to create a instantiate a structure, initiate its fields according to the values, create a publication object and call the method "publish" of that object with the structure as an argument. To simplify all these steps for many uORB topics, I need this class.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a solution myself. There is something called "Pointer to member". I found an explanation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=only-pointers-members-c). Using that, my example code from above looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct1
{
    int age;
    double height;
};


struct myStruct2
{
    float weight;
};

template<typename T, typename S>
class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass(T structure, S T::* ptr_field)
            : _structure {structure}
            , _ptr_field {ptr_field}
        {}

        void alterField(double newVal)
        {
            _structure.*_ptr_field = static_cast<S>(newVal);
        }

        void outputFields()
        {
            // code that outputs fields
            // uses _structure
            // otherwise not important
        }

    private:
        T _structure;
        S T::* _ptr_field;
};

int main() {
    myClass<myStruct1, int> classInstance1 {myStruct1{14, 1.63}, &myStruct1::age};

    classInstance1.alterField(15);
    classInstance1.outputFields();
    
    myClass<myStruct2, float> classInstance2 {myStruct2{75.6}, &myStruct2::weight};

    classInstance1.alterField(73.8);
    classInstance1.outputFields();
}
```

Comment: Hehe, sorry, looks like the 3 of us had the same idea at the same time :)

Comment: Consider `void alterField(const S& newVal)`

Comment: @pptaszni Nice :D

Comment: @Jarod42 Just to omit the static_cast? I favor explicitly stating my intentions over consise code. Or is there another advantage to your suggestion?

Comment: Allow to work with non numerical member (as `std::string` ). Move possible warning about implicit conversion to caller site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointers-to-member to represent a specific member of a class. In C++20, you can do it like this:

```
template<auto MP>
class myClass
{
    template <typename C, typename M> static C owner(M C::*);
    template <typename C, typename M> static M member(M C::*);
    using T = decltype(owner(MP));
    using FT = decltype(member(MP));
    public:
        template <typename... Args>
        explicit myClass(Args&&... args)
            : _structure {args...}
        {}

        void alterField(double newVal)
        {
            _structure.*MP = static_cast<FT>(newVal);
        }

        void outputFields()
        {
            // code that outputs fields
            // uses _structure
            // otherwise not important
        }

    private:
        T _structure;
};

int main() {
    myClass<&myStruct1::age> classInstance1 {14, 1.63};
    myClass<&myStruct2::weight> classInstance2 {75.6f};

    classInstance1.alterField(15);
    classInstance1.outputFields();

    classInstance2.alterField(73.8);
    classInstance2.outputFields();
}
```

See here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Edv8jKM3r

Comment: Oh, I answered my own question in the same second you did. Thank you! I

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that your major problem is the architecture design, not how to hack it in C++, but anyway I can answer some of your points:

> I want to have a class that has a member of an arbitrary struct type

OK, here we go:

```
template <typename SType>
class HackyClass {];
```

> The class should have a method that can alter the value of an arbitrary field of the struct member (...)

This is also possible (but rather not recommended without a good reason):

```
template <typename SType>
class HackyClass {
public:
    HackyClass(SType val): _val{val} {}
    template <typename VType>
    void setField(VType val, VType SType::* ptr) {
        _val.*ptr = val;
    }
    template <typename VType>
    VType getField(VType SType::* ptr) {
        return _val.*ptr;
    }

private:
    SType _val;
};
```

We are using here [pointers to member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer), the application might look like this:

```
struct S1 {
    int m_i;
    double m_d;
};

int main()
{
    S1 s1{1, 2.3};
    HackyClass hc1(s1);
    hc1.setField(4.5, &S1::m_d);
    std::cout << hc1.getField(&S1::m_d) << std::endl;
}
```

> (...) and another method that does something with the entire struct member (like outputting all its fields)

This is not possible without explicitly defining a method like `S1::printAllFields()` in the considered structure and calling it from your class. C++ doesn't have [reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632/4165552).

Here [small godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/bEovMG3bG).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You focused on the "output all fields" part. I should have omitted that. I do not need my class to find out all the fields of the arbitrary structure object. All I needed was a method, that has access to the entire structure. My problem is solved by the "pointers to member" stuff.